# Is there some oil, grease, or substance I can find at home or in the garage or office to lubricate a speed cube?

Tags: rubiks-cube, mechanical-puzzles

I'm backpacking around Asia randomly so I won't be ordering anything online.

But my speedcube has started to get a bit sticky and I'd like to lube it.

So what are some easy to get alternatives to the professional speedcube lubrication products sold online?

Is there something suitable that most of us already have at home?

- Must not damage or discolour plastics
- Must not corrode metal springs, screws, etc
- Must not be toxic, not irritate skin, etc
- Should not gunk up, attract dust, etc
- Should not stain fabrics

My cube is a Mo Fang Ge stickerless if that makes a difference.

Please do not recommend any brand name or store name. Just "what kind of stuff".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with the creation or the solving of puzzles.

Comment: @IAmInPLS See this [meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5454/are-questions-about-maintaining-repairing-improve-etc-physical-puzzles-such-a). I disagree. While not "spot on", I think it is okay here, given that the audience of this site (those who like or google rubik's puzzles) are the most likely to answer.

Comment: @BmyGuest I disagree because I think this is something which can be Googled easily.

Comment: This is better suited to an SE which deals with mechanical or physical objects. The fact that the object is used for puzzles, does not make a question about the object a question about puzzles. Thus it is not on-topic.

Comment: You should try and ask your question in chat. Someone might know someone, who could help you.

Comment: For what it's worth, I [firmly believe this question is on topic.](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5454/are-questions-about-maintaining-repairing-improve-etc-physical-puzzles-such-a) I do think the question would be better phrased as an inquiry into how to properly lubricate mechanical puzzles, though, as [shopping-style questions don't often work well on Stack Exchange.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: @Emrakul I agree that this question *could* be on-topic, but at the moment, it definitely looks like a shopping question.

Comment: @IAmInPLS That's fair. I should clarify that I mean to say I think the content is _categorically_ on topic, even if as worded it is currently a shopping question.

Comment: I firmly believe that anybody who is a mod or is down- or close-voting a question must first fully read and understand the SE blog post "Q&A is hard, let's go shopping!" before using it as a reason. Nevertheless I have edited the question to remove all traces of "shopping". If it is still closed I will *construct* my own twisty puzzle and a question here when I get to the step of lubricating it since constructing puzzles remains on-topic here.

Comment: https://www.speedsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Lubrication

Comment: Ask on quora... maybe u'll get an answer

Comment: @TejasvaDhyani: I was gonna ask on Quora initially but then recalled SE had a site for puzzles so came here first.

Comment: Go for the tube of silicone lube, not a spray. **Don't** try the most obvious thing most of us have a home - WD-40 - it's good for many similar jobs, but not this one.

Comment: If it's any help, my cube got faster by just using it over and over again.

Comment: @IanMacDonald: Yeah some get faster and some get slower. This one has started to jam and even get close to popping, which it never did when it was brand new and very lubey (-:

Answer (score 12):

You should try silicone spray aerosol, you should be able to find it in any hardware store.

It seems my answer is too short, so I'll add a little poem, I hope it will please you guys.

```
Roses are red
Violets are blue
Your cube is rough
So what can you do?
```

With love.

Comment: Your answer has been [automatically flagged as low-quality](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24183) due to its length. Perhaps you could flesh it out to give a bit more detail as to why this is a good choice?

Comment: Replace the poem with a pic?

Comment: @hippietrail what do you mean ?

Comment: A photo, an image, of such a substance or somebody lubing a cube with such. Or a link to some resource that recommends it in detail.

Comment: you should have gone with:
Roses are red,
My name's Dave,
I'm bad a poems,
Microwave...

Comment: [Apparently, at least some silicon sprays "eat" cubes.](https://www.speedsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Lubrication#CRC_Silicone_Spray)

Comment: rather than a poem, how about an explanation of why silicone spray aerosol is a good choice? And perhaps what it is called in Asia? I'm curious why you think something as large and bulky as an aerosol spray is the best choice for a backpacker. Is it because nothing non-aerosol will work?

Comment: @KateGregory it's a good choice because it's easy to find, and not so hard to carry I think... anyway, I don't think he is going to lub it every morning.

Comment: You can't take aerosol cans on planes either...

Comment: @hippietrail yes but you don't need to lub it everyday, do you ?